# Express JS res.redirect is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js, passport-facebook

I follow this [tutorial](https://hackhands.com/mongodb-crud-mvc-way-with-passport-authentication/) on how to use passport-facebook in MEAN stack, I got this error when I try to use `res.redirect('/signup')` I always get this error: `ReferenceError: res is not defined`

it seems like I didn't pass `res` as a parameter in my function. I try to add it at second / last parameters. but nothing works. What do I miss???

Here is my code:

```
exports.saveOAuthUserProfile = function(req, profile, done){
    User.findOne({
        provider: profile.provider,
        providerId: profile.providerId,
    },
    function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        }
        else
        {
            if (!user) {
                // console.log(profile.email.value);
                var possibleUsername = profile.username || ((profile.email) ? profile.email.value.split('@')[0] : '');
                User.findUniqueUsername(possibleUsername, null, function(availableUsername){
                    profile.username = availableUsername;
                    user = new User(profile);

                    user.save(function(err){
                        if (err) {
                            var message = getErrorMessage(err);
                            // var message = _this.getErrorMessage(err);
                            req.flash('error', message);
                            return res.redirect('/register');
                        }

                        return done(err, user);
                    });
                });
            }
            else
            {
                return done(err, user);
            }
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: @zerkms I only follow the tutorial, what is res when I console.log it? it said `res is undefined`. have you see the tutorial? sorry I am new to this MEAN stack

Comment: "I only follow the tutorial" --- then you don't follow it precisely. Check what `res` is in the tutorial.

Comment: @zerkms the code I posted in my question is the one in the tutorial, the tutorial didn't mention what `res` is, I assumed it must be a `response` callback or something.

Comment: Well, seems like the tutorial contains broken code. `res` variable is not defined so it does not exist. Probably author of that article should have posted less memes and check their code one more time instead.

Comment: @zerkms finally you realized it

Comment: You won't believe, but stackoverflow is to help you with your code, not to check the other people wrong articles. Do you have any other questions btw?

Comment: Use `req.res.redirect()` as a quick fix.

Comment: @robertklep hi thanks man, it works like a charm, thanks a lot :D